# Create a web page using jsp and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I'm new to working in angular.js with jsp . But i have some knowledge in creating web application using angularjs and node.js

i need some good guidance or any link to learn angularjs with jsp(java technologies).

if anyone have sound knowledge in angularjs and jsp please share somethings to learn or paste here some sampe codes.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265217/integrating-jsp-with-angularjs-is-it-a-concern-in-real-world-beginer-in-angul.

Comment: JSPs are used to generate HTML dynamically on the server. The principle of angular is to use static HTML templates and generate HTML dynamically on the client. You shouldn't need JSPs when using angular.