# AngularJS inside JSP page

Tags: angularjs, jsp, development-environment

I'm working on a project where all may work is  jsp  pages can i add AngularJS inside these pages , i'm also new to Angular

Comment: You surely can. but whether or not you can get all the benefits out of it depends on your design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating JSP with AngularJS, Is it a concern in real world...Beginer in Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265217/integrating-jsp-with-angularjs-is-it-a-concern-in-real-world-beginer-in-angul)

Answer (score 0):

I work on a web project, which renders a lot of graphs and animation charts to end users. We have been using the AngularJS  in the jsp for some time and this works fine for us. With jsp, one can easily determine the request context (for e.g  the request context URI for another link) on the webpage. With AngularJS, we develop the json returning services on server side and process the data via angularJS directives.