# Mixing front-end and server-side technologies (Spring, Thymeleaf, AngularJS)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm a newbie in web application development and try to explore some technologies. I have some (very) small experience with Spring-MVC and AngularJS. Recently, I've started to learn Thymeleaf.

Having some really basic knowledge of these technologies, I'm trying to figure out whether and how to use them jointly.

I know there are combinations like REST API as a Spring-MVC controller + AngularJS as a front-end technology that consumes the given data. And that's might be enough for your Single Page Application. But what about applications consisting of many pages which should reuse some components (ex. navbars)? And what about including security mechanisms in those applications?

I've just got to know that there exists Thymeleaf which seems to be a decent template engine. So far I've only used it to create some templates for my HTMLs, but I've heard there are many more appliances - like taking advantage of its nice integration with Spring.

I'm going to create web application consisting of a few pages with security mechanisms (registration, logging etc.), database integration and a lot of user interaction. It would be sort of order system.

Does it make any sense to mix front-end technology like Angular and back-end's Thymeleaf, especially in my case?

I've seen nice post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557805/angularjs-with-spring-mvc), but still need some clarification.

Comment: if you are new at it I wouldn't mix template engines rather  make up your mind if you are creating a server side app or client side one

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest [jhipster](http://jhipster.github.io/). Recently I wrote application with this API and I think its one of the best startup for application with back-end based on SpringMVC and front-end with AngularJS. You can easily generate template from command line which is fully editable